# Decode the utf8 to ISO-8859-1 mail subject to text in .procmailrc file

Tags: perl, email, encoding, utf8-decode, procmail

Set out to write a simple procmail recipie that would forward the mail if it found the text "ABC Store: New Order" in the subject.

```
 :0
    * ^(To|From).*abc@cdefgh.com
    * ^Subject:.*ABC Store: New Order*
    {
```

Unfortunately the subject field in the mail message coming from the mail server was in MIME encoded-word syntax.

Subject: =?UTF-8?B?QUJDIFN0b3JlOiBOZXcgT3JkZXI=?=

The above subject is utf-8 ISO-8859-1 charset, So was wondering if there are any mechanisms/scripts/utilities to parse this and convert to string format so that I could apply my procmail filter.

Comment: What you are looking at is a RFC2047-encoded header. Like it says in the charset part, it is in UTF-8, base64-encoded.  There is no ISO-8859-1 here (that's a different encoding; it can't be in ISO-8859-1 aka Latin-1 if it's in UTF-8).

Comment: In the general case, the repertoire of UTF-8 is much larger than the repertoire of ISO-8859-1, so you will not always be able to translate UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. If you only care about unwrapping the RFC2047 encoding and recovering the UTF-8 text, that's always possible (and perhaps a better thing to do).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use perl one liner to decode `Subject:` before assigment to procmail variable.

```
# Store "may be encoded" Subject: into $SUBJECT after conversion to ISO-8859-1
:0 h
* ^Subject:.*=\?
SUBJECT=| formail -cXSubject: | perl -MEncode=from_to -pe 'from_to $_, "MIME-Header", "iso-8859-1"'

# Store all remaining cases of Subject: into $SUBJECT
:0 hE
SUBJECT=| formail -cXSubject:

# trigger recipe based also on $SUBJECT content
:0
* ^(To|From).*abc@cdefgh.com
* SUBJECT ?? ^Subject:.*ABC Store: New Order
{
....
}
```

---

Comment (2020-03-07): It may be better to convert to UTF-8 charset instead of ISO-8859-*.

Comment: Nice. I had no idea that `MIME-Header` was an available encoding

Comment: Though the `r*` in the regex `New Order*` is kind of silly, and arguably wrong.

Comment: Why is the command for the "remaining cases" like this: `SUBJECT=| formail -cXSubject` **without a colon**, unlike the command for the first case: `SUBJECT=| formail -cXSubject: |`?

Comment: I have fixed example to syntax as in `man formail` examples.  Basic test of ` formail -cXSubject` seem to produce correct results too.

Comment: The argument to `formail -x` is just a string prefix; without the colon you will extract every header which *starts* with `Subject`; of course, in practice, unless you are running a fuzz tester or something, only `Subject:` will actually match.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`MIME::EncWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::EncWords).

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use MIME::EncWords 'decode_mimewords';

my $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?QUJDIFN0b3JlOiBOZXcgT3JkZXI=?=';
my $decoded = decode_mimewords($subject);
say $decoded;
```

**output**

```
ABC Store: New Order
```

Comment: This only unwraps the RFC2047 encoding; the result is still in UTF-8.  Because the OP's regex doesn't contain any characters where the encoding differs between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8, it doesn't seem to matter; but if you want to match text which is not pure ASCII, the encoding does matter, and you should know which encoding you are using.  (Like I argue in another comment, I would actually suggest to keep everything in UTF-8; but that is perhaps not what the OP is requesting. Though the question is unclear on this part.)